# Passing a value from javascript to Action Result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass a variable form javascript to an action result, I dont get any errors but I cant get it to work either.

I have the following javascript that when a user selects an item the item they select should be passed into the action result.

```
.on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
//alert('You selected node: ' + data.node.text);
url.actionURL("/SinqLaison/UpdateItemData", data.node.text);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateItemData", "SinqLaison")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { query: data.node.text }
});
```

The action result I am trying to pass the query to is

```
public ActionResult UpdateItemData(string query)
    {
        List<MarketItem> items = new List<MarketItem>();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connString;
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Items where Id =" + query , connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = new MarketItem()
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                marketParentGroup = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MarketGroup"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["MarketGroup"])),
                icon = reader["Icon"].ToString()
            };
            items.Add(item);
        }
        connection.Close();

        return View();
```

I get the following 404 error in the FireFox debugger. I'm sure the action and controller are correct. Is my javascript sysntax wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your code should pass whatever the value of `data.node.text` to the action method. Why do you think it is not happening ? Do you have any js errors in your page which is preventing your js code to execute ? Also read about Sql Injection attacks !

Comment: Hi Shyju, I set a breakpoint on the action result to see if it is being hit but the break point is never fired, I usually write my sql while developing then move it all over to stored procedures once I know its working correctly.

Comment: Do you have other js errors  ? Are you sure the `on` event is being called ?

Comment: just checked the the FireFox debugger and I get a 404 not found. So at least I know the event is fireing.

Comment: is your action method marked with `[HttpPost]` ?

Comment: Is your js code in a razor view file ? It should be because you are using the helper methods

Comment: Yes, just dosent seem to find the action or controller, ah i see the java script has to be in the razor view, I have the code in a seperate .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, It looks like your code is placed inside an external javascript file. The `@Url.Action` helper method is a C# method, which needs to be placed in a file which the server executes. The view file is the place for this. the server cannot execute your C# method calls placed in a javascript file.

You need to execute the `Url.Action` method in the view and pass that to the external js file.

So in your view file, execute the `Url.Action` helper method and store that value (the relative url) to a javascript variable. You need to make sure you are doing this before loading the script which has your ajax call. Also make sure to use javascript namespacing to avoid overwriting of evil global variables.

```
<script>
    var myProj = myProj || {};
    myProj.urls = myProj.urls || {};
    myProj.urls.updateItemDataUrl='@Url.Action("UpdateItemData", "Home")';    
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyExternalJsFileWhichHasAjaxCode.js"></script>
```

Now in your external javascript file, you can access it like

```
$.ajax({
    url: myProj.urls.updateItemDataUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { query: 'myTest' }
});
```